# Whats the best way to plot/draw projected stock price in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I have code some logics to project a few different possible path for stock price of certain security. The project actually is dynamic and will change as spot price changes. I basically would like to achieve something like the "bar patterns" function on the charting front end through a script.

I tried using line.new to do the projection, it works but there is a limitation of around 50 lines per chart in TradingView. Drawing a line to represent the projected high low range for each bar, possible 3 paths and projecting 90 days would mean 90 * 3 = 270 lines - whihc already exceeded the limit. So doesnt quite work.

plot with offset cant work under if/loop statements.

How do you guys accomplish something like this?

thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both `study()` and `strategy()` have a parameter : `max_lines_count` which allows you to extend the line limit to a maximum of 500 lines. eg

`study(title = "My study", overlay = true, max_lines_count = 500)`